# Microsoft Graph API / C# SDK can't find Security Group by Display Name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using the Microsoft .NET Graph SDK to query Groups with the query listed below (passing in searchText to search by Display Name). I've noticed a Group is not coming back in the results despite the correct query parameter and I'm trying to figure out why.

The Group is a Security Group of Source 'Cloud' that was created in January 2014 if that helps. I've been able to successfully query other Groups in this Tenant of this type just fine, I am wondering if there is a property I am missing or if maybe older Groups can't be queried this way?

```cs
var groups = await graphClient.Groups
  .Request()
  .Filter($"startsWith(displayName,'{searchText}')")
  .Select(g => new
  {
    g.Id,
    g.DisplayName,
  })
  .Top(10)
  .GetAsync();
```

Comment: What do you get back as a result?

Comment: Some response headers, a 200, but a CurrentPage with a count of 0 and a null NextPageRequest and nothing in the Results View in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)? It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @ShivaKeshavVarma that gave me a great idea and helped me find the solution!! I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after using Graph Explorer I was able to find the Group by Object Id, and after doing a query of the Group by Object Id using the GraphClient above I was able to figure out what was wrong. There was a space in front of the Display Name of the Group ie: " GroupName". So when querying by Display Name and StartsWith, what is passed in is taken quite literally with no trimming. Searching by display name with the above code and the space in the front worked to find the Group.

Comment: This is more comment than you might imagine. Most of the UI's should handle trimming the name for you, but Groups created via code or by syncing with a local AD can easily end up in this situation. You might want to write a script that searches for startsWith(displayName, ' ') and does a quick `PATCH` with a trimmed value.